# How to modify the password of elasticsearch in docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I want to modify the password of the container created by the elasticsearch image，I have executed the following orders

```
setup-passwords auto
```

but it did't work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBFoq.png)

```
unexpected response code [403] from GET http://172.17.0.2:9200/_xpack/security/_authenticate?pretty
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of posting the relevant error message in an externally hosted image, can you copy and paste the text from your terminal and include it as part of the question?

Comment: Unexpected response code [403] from calling GET http://172.17.0.2:9200/_xpack/se
curity/_authenticate?pretty
Possible causes include:
 * The relative path of the URL is incorrect. Is there a proxy in-between?
 * The protocol (http/https) does not match the port.
 * Is this really an Elasticsearch server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using docker it is usually best to configure services via environment variables. To set a password for the elasticsearch service you can run the container using the env variable ELASTIC_PASSWORD:

```
docker run -e ELASTIC_PASSWORD=`openssl rand -base64 12` -p 9200:9200 --rm --name elastic docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-platinum:6.2.4
```

`openssl rand -base64 12` sets a random value for the password

Comment: thank you very much，you've solved what I haven't solved in a day

Comment: :) You're welcome! Remember to mark the answer as correct if it solved the question